# Creating new feature classes from tuple using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, feature-class, error-000358, typeerror

I have point Feature Class that includes 49 `OID`. After that I have a Tuple that includes random set of `OID` from point feature class for example `new_OID = ('10,24,38,41', '17,26,34,47', '5,7,18,25', '7,12,26,46', '2,12,23,36', '7,18,21,43', '2,13,16,39', '5,8,32,43', '1,9,17,44', '8,13,30,46', '2,14,34,37')`.

How can I create new feature class for each `new_OID` member?

For example, my first feature class create by `(5,7,21,24)`  and so on and so forth.

```
import arcpy
in_FC = "E:/gis payannameh/TABU search/data/90spring_new.shp"
out_FC = r'E:\gis payannameh\Pychram_tabu\vince.gdb'
new_OID = ('10,24,38,41', '17,26,34,47', '5,7,18,25', '7,12,26,46', '2,12,23,36', '7,18,21,43', '2,13,16,39', '5,8,32,43', '1,9,17,44', '8,13,30,46', '2,14,34,37')


 for i in range(len(new_OID)):
     templayer = "templayer_{}".format(i)
     sql = """ {0} IN ({1})""".format("FID",new_OID[i])
     arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_FC,"templayer",sql)
     arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(templayer,out_FC,"MAKE_FC_{}".format[i])
```

`[u'0.shp', u'1.shp', u'10.shp', u'2.shp', u'3.shp', u'4.shp', u'5.shp', u'6.shp', u'7.shp', u'8.shp', u'9.shp']`

Comment: You created the variable `subset` -- use it when formatting `sql` (though you should add a space after the `IN` operator, and should NOT use `str()` around `subset` since integers don't get quoted)

Comment: `"{} IN ({})".fomat(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(in_FC, "FID"), subset)`

Comment: Furthermore, `out_FC` is a file geodatabase, not a feature class, so the variable name is a bit misleading.  Plus you appear to be attempting to overwrite the same feature class at each iteration of the loop (ie, to "MAKE_FC" within that fGDB each time).

Comment: @user2856. I have question . when I want to make feature class for `i=2` gis  show me `MAKE_FC_10` but I want to create `MAKE_FC_2` .  How can I name them in order?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (untested):

```py
import arcpy
in_FC = "E:/gis payannameh/TABU search/data/90spring_new.shp"
out_workspace = "E:/gis payannameh/Pychram_tabu/vince.gdb"
new_OID = ('2,24,28,42', '3,5,13,38', '2,17,20,47', '9,16,27,34')

for i in range(len(new_OID)):
    templayer = "templayer_{}".format(i)
    sql = "{} IN ({})".format("FID", new_OID[i])
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_FC, templayer, sql)
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(templayer, out_workspace, "MAKE_FC_{}".format(i))
```

Here, I'm iterating through `new_OID` with the `i` variable.  This can be used in both the `sql` formulation as well as in the output field name in the `FeatureClassToFeatureClass`.

I'm also using the variable name `out_workspace` instead of `out_FC` just because I think it makes more sense.

Additionally, I've changed the `out_workspace` string value to use slash (`/`) instead of back-slash (`\`) and the `r` prefix, just for the sake of consistency with the string on the previous line (could have changed the previous line instead, but either way, it's nice to have some consistency).

Alternatively, if you have specific names that you want to use for your new output feature classes (instead of, "MAKE_FC_0" to "MAKE_FC_3"), you could try something like this (untested):

```py
import arcpy
in_FC = "E:/gis payannameh/TABU search/data/90spring_new.shp"
out_workspace = 'E:/gis payannameh/Pychram_tabu/vince.gdb'
out_FC_OIDs = {'thingy': '2,24,28,42', 'blah': '3,5,13,38', 'custard': '2,17,20,47', 'rhubarb': '9,16,27,34'}

for fc_name in out_FC_OIDs:
    templayer = "templayer_{}".format(fc_name)
    sql = "{} IN ({})".format("FID", out_FC_OIDs[fc_name])
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_FC, templayer, sql)
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(templayer, out_workspace, fc_name)
```

Ie, using a dictionary with output feature class names as keys and corresponding OIDs as values.

Comment: I have a question. For first solution that you recommended If we assume  length `(New_OID) = 10`. So the arcpy create `MAKE_FC_0` and `MAKE_FC_1` and `MAKE_FC_10` Respectively. so I want to create for `i=2`,`MAKE_FC_2` but it shows me `MAKE_FC_10`. What is your suggestion?@SonofaBeach

Comment: I don’t understand the question, sorry.  It should create MAKE_FC_0 … MAKE_FC_9 (including MAKE_FC_2).